# Flutter keeps installing android platform SDK in every new projects

Tags: java, android, flutter

Every time I create a new flutter project it starts installing android SDK platform 28.
I am using flutter v1.17.4 with VSCode. The default compiled SDK version for every new project is 28 and I need to change it to 29 so it should install the updates only once because in the SDK location I can see platform v28 is already installed but it keeps installing it every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling and updating the Android Studio and android-SDK solved the problem.